# Use CSS to cut out shape

Tags: css

The effect I am trying to get is that I have a shape infront of another shape and where that shape is the background is visible. Ideally just the outline but cutting the whole shape out will be ok as I could then draw another shape inside.

Here is a snippet to show what I mean

```css
.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 15px solid #000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  
}

body{
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.com/photos/6-jTZysYY_U/download");
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="inner-box"></div></div>
```

Instead of the black outline I want to be able to see the background where the outline is, or have the whole square cut out.

Comment: Which browsers do you have to support? Is IE9 and lower support required?

Comment: No, as long as I can set a fallback style for older browsers so it degrades nicely then its fine.

Comment: Does the element on top have a solid color? That is, is the red colored going to be just a colored fill (or) a gradient/image?

Comment: @Harry It will be a gradient

Comment: Then it probably needs a mask (or) clip-path and those have very poor browser support (fallback would be no transparent cut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **SVG** approach with [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/6a/22/e3/6a22e387a2c72af177b2fa22ec71cbaa.jpg");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<svg width="50%" height="70%">
   <mask x='0' y='0' id="cut">
     <rect y='0' x='0' width="100%" height='100%' fill="white"/>
     <rect y='40%' x='40%' width="15%" height='15%' stroke-width="3%" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
   </mask>
   <rect y='0' x='0' width="100%" height='100%' fill="#fff" mask="url(#cut)"/>
</svg>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/6a/22/e3/6a22e387a2c72af177b2fa22ec71cbaa.jpg");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<svg width="50%" height="70%">
   <mask x='0' y='0' id="cut">
     <rect y='0' x='0' width="100%" height='100%' fill="white"/>
     <rect y='35%' x='35%' width="25%" height='25%'/>
   </mask>
   <rect y='0' x='0' width="100%" height='100%' fill="#fff" mask="url(#cut)"/>
</svg>
```